# Regular Expression negative lookahead to prevent the last character from being a hyphen

Tags: regex

I'm trying to capture a word or multiple words between 2 and 30 characters.  These characters can contain ., ', or -.   This regular expression accomplishes this.

```
[A-Za-z.'-]{2,30}
```

However the one caveat is that I need to make sure the last character is not a hyphen, my attempts at negative lookahead seems to be overruled by the fact that the first match allows hyphens.

I'd be grateful if somebody has a solution that would solve this problem in one regular expression.

Comment: don't escape special characters in character class.

Comment: thanks, i actually did not initially but a co-worker told me to do so, I will edit the question.

Comment: [-A-Za-z.']{2,29}[^-]

Comment: @qdii, this wouldn't match 2 character strings as I believe the OP wants. It also would match stuff like `F-&` which I don't believe the OP wants.

Comment: @smerny you are completely right! I will leave my comments though, for future reader who wonder how not to match a character (the construct `[^-]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following.

```
[a-zA-Z.'-]{1,29}[a-zA-Z.']
```

**Explanation**:

```
[a-zA-Z.'-]{1,29}     # any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z',
                      # '.', ''', '-' (between 1 and 29 times)

[a-zA-Z.']            # any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z', '.', '''
```

Answer (score 4):

Yet another way to solve this problem

```
[A-Za-z.'-]{2,30}(?<!-)
```

Placing [negative-look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) `(?<!-)` after `[A-Za-z.'-]{2,30}` ensures that last character from this match is not `-`. In other words there is no `-` right before place after match of `[A-Za-z.'-]{2,30}`

Comment: Is this available on all flavors of regex?

Comment: @qdii Probably not, for instance JavaScript doesn't support look-behind, but since question is not tagged with any specific language I decided to post this as other possible way to solve described problem.

Answer (score 2):

Match all but the last character one way, then match the last character as non-hyphen:

```
[A-Za-z.'-]{1,29}[A-Za-z.']
```

Comment: Thanks this is a perfect answer, it was about 20 seconds behind hwnd so i have to give him the credit with the actual answered question but I am upvoting this.  Thank you.